# How to order list according to array values in python?

Tags: python, list, vector

Lets say I have:

```
list = ['apple','banana','pear','orange']
values = [3,1,2,4]
```

I need to order the list strings according to their values in the "values" vector. In MatLab I would have merged the two then sort the vector, but it doesn't seem like I can do that here. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Don't name a variable `list`. You'll be sorry.

Comment: Yeah I just put that here as an example.

Comment: @Haidro: the expected output is exactly what jabaldonedo posted. He answered my question perfectly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This could work for you. Use `zip` to pair both lists and then sort, finally get the new list.

```
>>> mylist = ['apple','banana','pear','orange'] 
>>> values = [3,1,2,4]
>>> [i[1] for i in sorted(zip(values, mylist))]
 ['banana', 'pear', 'apple', 'orange']
```

By the way don't use `list` for naming your list.

You can also use `itertools.izip` which is like `zip()` except that it returns an iterator instead of a list, and therefore you can get better performance

```
>>> from itertools import izip
>>> mylist = ['apple','banana','pear','orange'] 
>>> values = [3,1,2,4]
>>> [i[1] for i in sorted(izip(values, mylist))]
 ['banana', 'pear', 'apple', 'orange']
```

Comment: zip is the function I was missing! Thank you!

Comment: you are welcome, check my last update about `izip`, and remember that the best way to say thank you in SO is by either upvoting/accepting answers ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try using numpy argsort. Change the list and values to numpy array

```
list = np.asarray( list )
values = np.asarray( values )

idxs = np.argsort(values)
list = list[:,idxs]
```

Just got it in my mind. Haven't tested this, but I think that should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Better to use Dict object, if key value pair present use the dict it easy to process....

Answer (score -1):

This should do it:

```
[i[1] for i in sorted(enumerate(list), key=lambda (ix, _): values[ix])]
```

gives

```
['banana', 'pear', 'apple', 'orange']
```

**EDIT:** jabaldonedo's answer is definitely the best one.